# Cómo manipular un JSON ARRAY en Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, jsonarray

hola amigos estoy recoger datos de este JSON

```
{
  "Cabecera": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "cedula": "0932474152",
      "nombres": "Victor",
      "apellidos": "Jaramillo",
      "Seguros": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "usuario_id": 1,
            "seguro_id": 1,
                "plan": {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Contra Incendios",
            "Valor": "250",
            "tipo": "mensual",
           
          }
        }
```

en la que solo puedo obtener los datos de INICIALES oseas los datos de la CABECERA
pero necesito obtener los datos de SEGUROS y de PLAN.

adjuntos mi codigo en java de como obtengo la cabecera

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray data = object.getJSONArray("cabecera");
                System.out.println("1-----------" + data);
                   
                     for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){

                    JSONObject object3 = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String cedula = object3.getString("cedula");
                    
                    System.out.println("-----------" + cedula);

                   

                  
                }
```

en el PRIMER SOUT muestro todo el JSON pero no se como navegar y que me vaya mostrando SEGUROS y luego PLAN en el SEGUNDO SOUT muestro un dato de la CABECERA , aconséjenme porfavor

Answer (score 5):

Si revisas la estructura de tu Json los array, dentro del array "Cabecera" tienes un array "Seguros" y dentro de este array "Seguros" tienes un objeto "plan", lo que tienes que realizar es obtener el elemento (Array u Objeto) e iterar para obtener sus valores:

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray data = null;
    data = object.getJSONArray("Cabecera");

    System.out.println("1-----------" + data);
    for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){

        JSONObject object3 = data.getJSONObject(i);
        String cedula = object3.getString("cedula");
        System.out.println("-----------" + cedula);

        //Array Seguros
        JSONArray arraySeguros = object3.getJSONArray("Seguros");
        for(int j=0;j<arraySeguros.length();j++) {
            JSONObject objectSeguros = arraySeguros.getJSONObject(i);
            String usuarioId = objectSeguros.getString("usuario_id");
            System.out.println("usuarioId: " + usuarioId);

            //Object Plan
            JSONObject objectPlan = objectSeguros.getJSONObject("plan");
            String nombre = objectPlan.getString("nombre");
            System.out.println("nombre: " + nombre);

        }

    }
```